# Tkinter Buttons lose functionality when I invoke it from another python file

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am new to Tkinter and I want to do this for my college project. I was going to do a simple app launcher with calculator, clock and a notes app from a `main.py`. I looked online and found various methods to import other python files. I used **init**.py to do it.

**init**.py

```
from .clock_app import open_clock
from .notes_app import open_notes
from .calc_app import open_calc
```

This is the code for my main file (app launcher).

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button, PhotoImage
import Apps

def main():
    root = Tk()
    #Icons
    root_icon = PhotoImage(file="Assets/app_launcher_icon.png")
    #main root properties
    
    
    root.title("App Launcher")
    root.geometry("700x500")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.configure(bg="#49de71")
    root.iconphoto(False,root_icon)
    
    #Functions for each app added
    

    #Icons
    
    
    #Buttons to open each app

    calendar_button = Button(root, text="Clock",command = Apps.open_clock)
    calendar_button.place(x=239,y=5)
    calendar_button.config(height=20,width=30)

    calculator_button = Button(root,text="Calculator",command = Apps.open_calc)
    calculator_button.config(height=20,width=30)
    calculator_button.place(x=472,y=5)

    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this is the code to the calculator,

```
from tkinter import *

class calc_app:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Calculator")
        root.destroy()
        # Create widgets for the second window
        # from here
        global expression
        expression=""
        
        #to update expression in text box
        def press(num):
            global expression
            expression = expression + str(num)
            equation.set(expression)
            
        def equalpress():
            try:
                global expression
                total = str(eval(expression))
                equation.set(total)
                expression=""
                
            except:
                equation.set(" error ")
                expression=""
        
        def clear():
            global expression
            expression = ""
            equation.set("")
            
        calculator=Tk()
        calculator.configure(background="#07398a")
        calculator.geometry("350x300")
        calculator.resizable(False,False)
        
        equation = StringVar()
        expression_field = Entry(calculator,textvariable=equation,width=30,font=('Arial', 20))
        expression_field.place(x=0,y=0)
        
        button7 = Button(calculator, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(7), height=2, width=10) 
        button7.place(x=5,y=55)

        button8 = Button(calculator, text=' 8 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(8), height=2, width=10) 
        button8.place(x=90,y=55)

        button9 = Button(calculator, text=' 9 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(9), height=2, width=10) 
        button9.place(x=175,y=55)
        
        button4 = Button(calculator, text=' 4 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(4), height=2, width=10) 
        button4.place(x=5,y=105)

        button5 = Button(calculator, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(5), height=2, width=10) 
        button5.place(x=90,y=105)

        button6 = Button(calculator, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(6), height=2, width=10) 
        button6.place(x=175,y=105)

        button1 = Button(calculator, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(1), height=2, width=10) 
        button1.place(x=5,y=155)

        button2 = Button(calculator, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(2), height=2, width=10) 
        button2.place(x=90,y=155)

        button3 = Button(calculator, text=' 3 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(3), height=2, width=10)  
        button3.place(x=175,y=155)

        button0 = Button(calculator, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press(0), height=2, width=10) 
        button0.place(x=90,y=205)

        plus = Button(calculator, text=' + ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
               command=lambda: press("+"), height=5, width=11)  
        plus.place(x=260,y=160)

        minus = Button(calculator, text=' - ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                       command=lambda: press("-"), height=3, width=11)
        minus.place(x=260,y=100)

        multiply = Button(calculator, text=' * ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press("*"), height=2, width=22) 
        multiply.place(x=5,y=255)

        divide = Button(calculator, text=' / ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press("/"), height=2, width=23) 
        #divide.grid(row=5, column=3) 
        divide.place(x=175,y=255)

        equal = Button(calculator, text=' = ', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
               command=equalpress, height=2, width=10) 
        #equal.grid(row=5, column=2) 
        equal.place(x=175,y=205)

        clear = Button(calculator, text='Clear', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
               command=clear, height=2, width=11) 
        #clear.grid(row=5, column='1')
        clear.place(x=260,y=55)

        Decimal= Button(calculator, text='.', fg='black', bg='#4287f5', 
                   command=lambda: press('.'), height=2, width=10) 
        #Decimal.grid(row=6, column=0) 
        Decimal.place(x=5,y=205)
        
        
        

       

def open_calc():
    calc = Toplevel()
    app = calc_app(calc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = calc_app(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The Clock app works fine.
The calculator app also works fine when i run it alone, but when i try to run it from the main file, the buttons don't seem to work.

I figured it was some sort of importing problem, but I didn't see anything that catered to what I was having. I followed the same step of the clock app i created that seems to work from the app launcher, but that didn't really seem to work out for the calculator.

Comment: you should be using the `if __name__=`__main__:` guard in the files.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Answer (score 0):

First you create a toplevel window `calc` inside `open_calc()` and pass it into `calc_app()`.  This toplevel window is then destroyed (`root.destroy()`) inside `calc_app.__init__()`.  Then you create another instance of `Tk()` (`calculator`).  The issue is caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.

You should not destroy the toplevel window and create another instance of `Tk()`, just use the toplevel window:

```py
class calc_app:
    def __init__(self, root):
        calculator = root
        calculator.title("Calculator")
        # don't destroy the toplevel
        #root.destroy()
        ...
        # don't create another instance of Tk()
        #calculator=Tk()
        ...
```

Note also that you should use instance variable `self.expression` instead of global variable `expression`.